# Javascript variable works only the first time

Tags: javascript, arrays, json

I have function that works with JSON.

```
    function makeItem(data){
    var tbl_body = "";
    $.each(data, function() {
        var id = parseInt(this.ProductId);
        var tbl_row = "";
            tbl_row += "<a href='article.php?cat=<?=$cat?>&subcat=<?=$subcat?>&id="+id+"'>";
            tbl_row += "<div class='subCatImg'><img src='imagesDB/articles/<?=$main["+id+"]['dir']?>/<?=$main["+id+"]['image']?>'></div>";
            tbl_row += "<div class='subCatName'>"+this.ProductNameBG+"</div>";
            tbl_row += "<div class='subCatText'>"+this.ProductNameBG+"</div>";
            tbl_row += "</a>";
        tbl_body += "<div class='categoryWrap'>"+tbl_row+"</div>";
    })
    return tbl_body;
}
```

The problem is that the variable id works only the first time - in the a tag but not in the second nor the third time.
Is it because the a tag is not immediately closed or because the second and the third time I'm trying to use it in php array. I'm sure that the array works because if I hardcore it(`<?=$main[1]['dir]?>`) the image is displayed(no need for quotation marks, I need integer).
The thing is that I have to make it dynamic so I can't just type some number.
Why does it work the first time but not the others?

Comment: PHP runs on the server....It can not run inside of JavaScript.

Comment: (which is to say that your `<?= ?>` code only runs the first time)

Comment: Completly forgot about that.....Any suggestions how to display my images?

Answer (score 0):

@epascarello is correct. PHP is server side, were JS is client side. Instead, try to do something like

**UPDATED:**

```
tbl_row += <?php print("\"<a href='article.php?cat=$cat&subcat=$subcat&id=\" + id + \"'>\""); ?>
tbl_row += <?php print("\"<div class='subCatImg'><img src='imagesDB/articles/$phpVal1/$phpVal2'></div>\""); ?>
tbl_row += <?php print("\"<div class='subCatName'>\" + this.ProductNameBG + \"</div>\"");?>
tbl_row += <?php print("\"<div class='subCatText'>\" + this.ProductNameBG + \"</div>\"");?>
tbl_row += <?php print("\"</a>\"");?>
```

In this, you will have to pass the value of the id and the dir from JS to php so php can parse it's multidimensional array. You'll notice that `<?=$main["+id+"]['dir']?>/<?=$main["+id+"]['image']?>` has changed to `$phpVal1/$phpVal2`.

You can do this a number of ways - perhaps through a click of a button. But php will be done first, and then the JS.

In essence, you are getting all the values from the server (php) and forcing it to write the client side (JS) for you.

Comment: I get `PHP Parse error:  syntax error, unexpected ']'` on this line `<?php print("tbl_row += \"<div class='subCatImg'><img src='imagesDB/articles/" . $main[+id+]['dir'] ."/". $main[+id+]['image'] . "'></div>")?>;` I have messed it somehow but not quite sure how to fix it

Comment: I think you are having an issue because you are passing javascript to php to javascript. The $main[+id+]['dir'] isn't going to work because you have told the php to write the javascript values... if you want to do this, you will have first pass the javascript values to the php.

Comment: I'm assuming that $main["+id+"]['image'] (particularly $main) is a php array?

Comment: Yes, multidimensional one

Comment: I've edited my answer to try and help better, but it's not going to be easy to do. I am guessing that you are trying to do an on-the-fly change to a page so no reload is required. This is still possible, but you may have to explore some AJAX or something similar to do it.

Comment: I'm going to try it. Thank you for your time

Answer (score 0):

You can convert your PHP array into a json object like this :

```
var main = <?php echo json_encode($main) ?>;
```

then iterate through it.